# How to scroll on multiple AmCharts simultaneously?

Tags: charts

I just started using AmCharts and have setup two line plots, one on top of the other, with their respective scrollbars.

Now, I want to "link" the scrollbars of both plots, so that if I move the scrollbar on the chart1, I'll get the same date range on the chart2. I imagine this shouldn't be too difficult with a listener, a get value function and a set value function, but I'm unable to find how to get the start/end values of the scrollbar so that I can play with them.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a demo for this in the AmCharts Knowledge Base

https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/share-scrollbar-across-several-charts/

This is the code that is syncing the scrollbars, (I have added the annotations):

Create an array to populate with your charts

```
var charts = [];
```

Create how ever many charts you need

```
charts.push(AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", chartConfig));
charts.push(AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", chartConfig2));
charts.push(AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv3", chartConfig3));
```

Iterate over the charts, adding an event listener for "zoomed" which will share the event handler

```
for (var x in charts) {
  charts[x].addListener("zoomed", syncZoom);
}
```

The event handler

```
function syncZoom(event) {
  for (x in charts) {
    if (charts[x].ignoreZoom) {
      charts[x].ignoreZoom = false;
    }
    if (event.chart != charts[x]) {
      charts[x].ignoreZoom = true;
      charts[x].zoomToDates(event.startDate, event.endDate);
    }
  }
}
```